# How to Return Different Values When Scanning a Barcode?

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am having an issue with returning two different values when scanning a barcode. Currently, when I scan the barcode, the same value is returned for both Text widgets. I need each Text widget to take a different value. How can I achieve this?

##### Screenshot: Barcode Scan

[image: BARCODE]

```
 String? scanResult;

 Future scanBarcode() async {
    String scanResult;
    try{

    scanResult = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode("#ff6666", "Cancel", true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
    } on PlatformException{
      scanResult = 'Failed to get platform verion';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() => this.scanResult = scanResult);
  }
```

##### My Code for show Scan-Results

```
  Text(
                    '$scanResult',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),

 Text(
                    '$scanResult',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
```

**My Question :** As shown in the attached image. I have two values in the data section.
How to display both data separately in two widgets?

Comment: Please help improve the grammar of the question. It's difficult to understand what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must capture and separate the result using split

```html
Text(
                    '${scanResult.split('\n')[0]}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),

 Text(
                    '${scanResult.split('\n')[1]}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),`
```